# Remote EJB jndi lookup fails

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jndi

Trying to access remote EJB on glassfish 4 server. Lookup is failed. Glassfish running on different JDK. what's wrong? SDK is IntelliJ IDEA.

Here what I have:

```
RobertImpl__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__: javax.naming.Reference
PhoenixImpl!robert.phoenix.PhoenixRemote: javax.naming.Reference
RobertImpl!robert.phoenix.PhoenixLocal: com.sun.ejb.containers.JavaGlobalJndiNamingObjectProxy
RobertImpl!robert.phoenix.PhoenixRemote: javax.naming.Reference
PhoenixImpl!robert.phoenix.PhoenixLocal: com.sun.ejb.containers.JavaGlobalJndiNamingObjectProxy
PhoenixImpl__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__: javax.naming.Reference
Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.
```

ejb module name ejbTest

Client code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
                "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "127.0.0.1");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);

        PhoenixRemote phoenix = (PhoenixRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/ejbTest/RobertImpl!robert.phoenix.PhoenixRemote");
        return;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/ejbTest/RobertImpl!robert.phoenix.PhoenixRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=127.0.0.1, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacerobert.phoenix.PhoenixRemote [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: robert.phoenix.PhoenixRemote]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacerobert.phoenix.PhoenixRemote [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: robert.phoenix.PhoenixRemote]
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:433)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.java:75)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:487)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: robert.phoenix.PhoenixRemote
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60340', transport: 'socket'
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.getBusinessIntfClassLoader(EJBUtils.java:685)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.loadGeneratedRemoteBusinessClasses(EJBUtils.java:462)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:413)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Did you try: Object o = ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/Foo");

Comment: When you deploy your application glassfish logs to console global and portable names for EJB interfaces. Example from my project  `[2017-03-20T17:36:53.435+0300] [Glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00054] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool(1)] [timeMillis: 1490020613435] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Portable JNDI names for EJB MyBean: [java:global/myApplication/MyBean!com.my.project.MyBean, java:global/myApplication/MyBean]]]` .Look at your logs or console output and try to lookup by this names